# NetBeans 8.2 External Execution Base API Missing for Scala Plugins

Tags: scala, netbeans

I am using NetBeans 8.2 to develop Scala application.

Some Scala plugins require: `"The plugin External Execution Base API is requested in implementation version 201510222201"`.

Can I download that API anywhere?

Comment: There is a Bugzilla entry for this, that appears to have been ignored because it is reported against a 3rd Party Plugin. Bugzilla: https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=258145.  The manual page: [External Execution API](http://bits.netbeans.org/dev/javadoc/org-netbeans-modules-extexecution/overview-summary.html)

Answer (score 5):

One of the frequent pull request submitters has an 8.2 plugin set [available for download](https://github.com/akochnev/nbscala/releases/tag/1.8.2.0).

Comment: Seems to work with the latest Netbeans 8.2 -- At least I can say Hello world.  https://github.com/akochnev/nbscala

Comment: Some further information -- I installed this plugin for Netbeans 8.2 <br/>
 <br/>
https://github.com/akochnev/nbscala <br/>

However it can not recognise the Scala package installed by SDKMAN.

Comment: +1 for this anwer. I went to akochnev's repo, downloaded the latest release at [https://github.com/akochnev/nbscala/releases/download/1.8.2.0/nbscala-plugins.zip], unzipped and found ```.nbm``` files that worked for Netbeans 8.2. Life of SCALA AWESOMENESS

Answer (score 4):

I've just ran into the same problem. The solution is the following:

1. Find out what version of the External Execution Base API you have in your Netbeans installation.
   In my case, it is noted in

> ..\NetBeans 8.2\ide\modules\org-netbeans-modules-extexecution-base.jar\META-INF\MANIFEST.MF

2. Edit the dependency definitions of the related nbscala nbm files.
   In my case I had to update the following files

> org-netbeans-modules-scala-sbt-1.8.1.0.nbm\Info\info.xml
>
> org-netbeans-modules-scala-sbt-1.8.1.0.nbm\netbeans\modules\org-netbeans-modules-scala-sbt.jar\META-INF\MANIFEST.MF
>
> org-netbeans-modules-scala-console-1.8.1.0.nbm\Info\info.xml
>
> org-netbeans-modules-scala-console-1.8.1.0.nbm\netbeans\modules\org-netbeans-modules-scala-console.jar\META-INF\MANIFEST.MF

3. Delete the nbm signatures, since the changes made it invalid

> org-netbeans-modules-scala-console-1.8.1.0.nbm\META-INF\NBSCALA.*
>
> org-netbeans-modules-scala-sbt-1.8.1.0.nbm\META-INF\NBSCALA.*

4. Install the modules and hope there won't be any issue encountered by this hack.

Comment: Could you please point out exactly what the dependency definition for External Execution Base API looks like? And how to add it?

Comment: Could you please provide an example?

Comment: I've already resolved the issue. Thanks, anyway for the above explanation.

Comment: Very nice hack, I can confirm that it works. Hopefully a new version of the plugin will be released soon.

Comment: Seems like I spoke too soon. The plugin installs and I am able to create a new hello world project, but atleast on my editor it is impossible to edit the newly created scala file. The file can be edited externally with a text editor and will then be updated in the netbeans editor, but cannot be edited in the netbeans editor itself (keystrokes are ignored in the editor window).

Comment: @mdewit I've experienced exactly the same problem. I hope there is some other solution.