# NetBeans 10 External Execution Base API issue

Tags: scala, netbeans-plugins, netbeans-10, netbeans-11

I have Apache NetBeans IDE 10. When I try to install the [nbscala](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/75542/nbscala) plugins for Scala, I get an issue:

```
Some plugins require plugin External Execution Base API to be installed
```

[image]

How do I fix the issue?

The [solutions for NetBeans 8.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41870393/netbeans-8-2-external-execution-base-api-missing-for-scala-plugins) don't work.

**Product Version:** Apache NetBeans IDE 10.0 (Build incubator-netbeans-release-380-on-20181217)
**nbscala plugin version:** 20190313-b8a704f058cc

Comment: Unfortunately I get the same problem as you with Apache NetBeans 10.0, and I am unwilling to attempt the hack in the SO post you linked to. That said, I don't believe that NetBeans 10.0 claims to formally support Scala, and I don't see any mention of [Scala in the outstanding NetBeans Bug Reports](https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/NETBEANS/issues/NETBEANS-2052?filter=allopenissues). Since this is a plugin issue rather than a NetBeans issue I'm not sure there's much that the NetBeans Team can do to help, but I suppose you could raise a Bug Report to see their response.

Comment: Same issue is observed in [Apache NetBeans IDE 11.0](https://netbeans.apache.org/download/nb110/index.html).

Comment: The github plugin has [a branch named **nb11.x**](https://github.com/cbm64chris/nbscala/tree/nb11.x). Did you try that with NetBeans 11.0? (It also has a branch for NetBeans 10.0.)